# How to roll back With OctoberCms?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

With OctoberCms, The CURRENT BUILD is 447, But I want to rollback 433, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

October uses a rolling-release system, which means you will always get the latest version using the installer.

However, if you use a [composer based installation](https://octobercms.com/docs/console/commands#console-install-composer), you can require a specific version tag. You can find the available tags on [packagist](https://packagist.org/packages/october/october).

Another option would be to pull the files directly from the git repository. Each new version is tagged as a release. You can find v433 [here](https://github.com/octobercms/october/releases/tag/v1.0.433), it would just be a bit tricky to install right from the git files.